# Gmod lua attempt to index a string value with bad key ('addMoney' is not part of the string library)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

When trying to run my script i keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] addons/moneymanagement/lua/autorun/derma.init.lua:7: attempt to index a string value with bad 
 key ('addMoney' is not part of the string library)
  1. error - [C]:-1
   2. __index - lua/includes/extensions/string.lua:297
    3. func - addons/moneymanagement/lua/autorun/derma.init.lua:7
     4. unknown - lua/includes/extensions/net.lua:32
```

Server side:

```
util.AddNetworkString("add_money")
net.Receive("add_money", function()
local currentplayer = net.ReadString()
local moneyamount = net.ReadUInt(24)
currentplayer:addMoney(moneyamount)

end)
```

Client side:

```
--add_money
addbutton = vgui.Create("DButton", f)
addbutton:Center()
addbutton:SetText("Add Money")
addbutton:SetSize(220, 80)
addbutton:SetPos(450, 65)
function addbutton:DoClick()
--Include net function here
--https://maurits.tv/data/garrysmod/wiki/wiki.garrysmod.com/index1b73.html
print("Sent playername " .. SelectedPlayer .. " and amount " .. input:GetValue() .. " to server") --debug
print(SelectedPlayer) --debug
net.Start("add_money")
net.WriteString(SelectedPlayer)
net.WriteUInt(input:GetValue(), 24)
net.SendToServer()
-- Still need to add server side net
-- Remember to define
    end
```

If you're confused as to where some integers are coming from it's from other parts of the script. Though i've already tested whether they work. Simply need some help with the networking.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
local currentplayer = net.ReadString()
```

is a string, you need something like:

```
local currentplayer = getPlayer(net.ReadString())
currentplayer:addMoney(moneyamount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going around the whole currentplayer concept.
Instead i decided to math the players steamid as shown below.

Server side:

```
util.AddNetworkString("add_money")


net.Receive("add_money", function()
--local currentplayer = net.ReadEntity()
local moneyamount = net.ReadUInt(24)
local currentplayersteamid = net.ReadString()
print("This is how much to give: " .. moneyamount)
print("current steamid " .. currentplayersteamid)

for k, v in pairs( player.GetAll()) do
--  print(v) --debug
    gather = v:SteamID()
if tostring(gather) == currentplayersteamid then

    v:addMoney(moneyamount)

return end
end
```

Client side:

```
--add_money
addbutton = vgui.Create("DButton", f)
addbutton:Center()
addbutton:SetText("Add Money")
addbutton:SetSize(220, 80)
addbutton:SetPos(450, 65)
function addbutton:DoClick()
--Include net function here
--https://maurits.tv/String/garrysmod/wiki/wiki.garrysmod.com/index1b73.html
print("Sent playername " .. SelectedPlayer .. " and amount " .. input:GetValue() .. " to server") --debug
print(SelectedPlayer) --debug
net.Start("add_money")
--net.WriteString(SelectedPlayer)
net.WriteUInt(input:GetValue(), 24)
net.WriteString(PlayerSteamID)
net.SendToServer()
-- Still need to add server side net
-- Remember to define
    end
```